# svnmerge vs svn merge

Tags: svn, merge, svn-merge

What is the difference between 'svnmerge' (alias [svnmerge.py](http://www.orcaware.com/svn/wiki/Svnmerge.py), the python script that comes with svn) and 'svn merge' (Subversion 1.5's native merge-tracking)? Which one do you recommend?

Comment: I suspect that `svnmerge` is an alias for `svn merge`

Comment: Well svnmerge doesn't contain a space and svn merge doesn't. I am also not sure this belongs on stackoverflow. Perhaps superuser.

Comment: My system doesn't have an svn merge, so I think Dana is right.

Comment: Tuure's post below may also be correct, it's impossible to tell which without more info from the Asker.

Comment: I found this page where svnmerge and switching to svn native merge tracking is mentioned (under "Merge tracking and compatibility"):
http://subversion.tigris.org/svn_1.5_releasenotes.html#merge-tracking. This is what I am talking about.

Comment: @Dana the Sane: `svnmerge` *is NOT* an alias for `svn merge`. `svnmerge` is a script to do basic merge tracking on top of old (before 1.5) releases of Subversion which provided no merge tracking of their own.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Prior to 1.5, the Subversion `merge` command didn't leave much information on which branches were reintegrated to the trunk, so svnmerge.py was written to make up for this lack of traceability.

Starting with version 1.5, meta-information is generated by svn at each merge, the `svn:mergeinfo` property which is transparently appended to the target paths. You can appreciate that for example if you use TortoiseSVN, which can show you a graph.

This is not perfect yet though, [as many would rightly say](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1621167/how-do-i-know-if-a-branch-has-already-been-merged-in-svn-mercurial-git).

So you should see what your needs are, if the standard `svn merge` is not enough for you, have a look at scripts like `svnmerge` but in that case, make sure everyone uses the same tool.

In my experience, the standard option is more than enough in most cases.

Comment: Does this answer implies that svn merge is less capable than svnmerge?

Comment: Not really since 1.5. There are some features in `svnmerge` that don't exist in the native Subversion merge, like keeping a list of merged/unmerged commits, blocking some revisions, but apparently the disadvantages can outweight those not-so-useful additional features, as you can see here: http://blogs.open.collab.net/svn/2007/10/subversion-15-m.html. Also, there are more and more reports of `svnmerge` problems with Subversion 1.6. You can see the feature list and FAQ on their website: http://www.orcaware.com/svn/wiki/Svnmerge.py

Comment: @RedGlyph: the blogs link you posted no longer exists. :-( so much for the idea of permalinks

Comment: @JasonS [The Wayback Machine still has a copy](https://web.archive.org/web/20090503105758/http://blogs.open.collab.net/svn/2007/10/subversion-15-m.html)

Answer (score 4):

[`svnmerge`](http://www.orcaware.com/svn/wiki/Svnmerge.py) is an external tool for "automatic branch management", whereas [`svn merge`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html) is the basic tool for mergin branches in Subversion itself. As you don't tell what you want to do, it's a bit hard to recommend either.